# How to get jquery default style after changing input style?

Tags: jquery, css, input

I have a text input which I validate its value when event "blur" triggers .
when the value is not valid , I change the input background color , and when I resolved the error I want the original color and style of the input to be set again to it .
but what's happening that I'm losing the original style after resolving the error or getting the error , in general that's happening when changing input's style .
I tried to look for the original style to set it again but I couldn't find it in jqueryui styles .
need your help :

HTML Code :

```
<input type='text' name='val1' id='val1'/>
```

jQuery Code :

```
function is_numeric(value)
{
    var pattern= new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
    return pattern.test(value);
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $('#val1').blur(function()
    {
        if(!is_numeric($('#val1').val()))
        {
            $('#val1').css('background-color','#E65050');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#va1').css('background-color','white '); /// here ??
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

please use `class`  see the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ateruj/1/edit)**

**CSS**

```
.error {background-color:#E65050}
```

**jQuery**

```
function is_numeric(value)
{
    var pattern= new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
    return pattern.test(value);
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $('#val1').blur(function()
    {
        if(!is_numeric($('#val1').val()))
        {
            $('#val1').addClass('error');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#va1').removeClass("error");
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store it at document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   var defColor = $('#val1').css('background-color');

   $('#val1').blur(function()
   {
    ...
    $('#val1').css('background-color', defColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
  $('#va1').css('background-color','white '); /// here ??
```

use

```
  $('#va1').css('background-color','');
```

Answer (score 1):

did you noticed the spelling mistake:

```
$('#va1').css('background-color','white ');
```

should be like this

```
$('#val1').css('background-color','white ');
```